# Java getTime() getting time from `time with time zone` not getting correctly

Tags: java, postgresql, time, timezone

I have `time with time zone` in my postgresql database. My location is India so it is stored as `10.00.00+5.30`. I am getting the result using java Resultset as follows:

Suppose:

`String time = rst.getTime(1).toString();`

Expected result is : `10:00` but I am getting result as `21.30`. Please guide me what I do wrong?

Comment: When you use toString, you "lose" the time zone information.

Comment: @ assylias agree. How can I get the correct time?

Comment: Keep in mind that Postgres doesn't actually store the time zone offset you send it.  It normalizes it to UTC before storing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DateFormat in order to set Time Zone to a parsed String.

```
SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
String time = isoFormat.format(rst.getTime(1));
```

Comment: I am just having `10.00.00+5.30` and not have `2010-05-23T09:01:02`.

Comment: @Santhucool You need to use a DateFormat with the correct time zone as detailed in this answer, then: `String time = isoFormat.format(rst.getTime(1));`